# Google cloud storage authentication confusion

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a newbie question regarding google cloud storage. I'm looking to create a website where people can upload files (similar to Flickr in concept) and view them. I was looking at google's cloud storage option and it seemed interesting. I got a little hung up on the authentication process. Do all users need a Google account or did I just misread it? I guess my question is can I create a site where everyone doesn't have to sign up for a google account? 
Thank you for your patience and help

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly necessary to require a user to be logged in in order to write to your bucket (e.g., we have a [public-read-write](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#applyacls) canned ACL for buckets), but it's generally a bad idea. Any data stored in your bucket will ultimately be charged to you, so allowing anyone to write without authentication opens you up to a great deal of abuse.

Likewise, you could make all of your objects public-read, but then you get charged for the bandwidth costs and have no control over it (though this is a much more reasonable thing to do than public-write).

A safer option would be to proxy bytes for your users - i.e., only you/your app can write to your bucket, and your users hand their bytes to you.

Generally speaking, though, the only types of authentication we support are Google accounts, signed URLs, and anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there's no need for customers to have their own Google accounts. Google Cloud Storage supports that, in case you want to say "these accounts have access to this data", but you can also let your app grant access on a per-request basis using whatever logic or authentication scheme you like.

This is usually accomplished with signed URLs. Basically, you'd use your credentials to sign a very specific request (download object X, upload an object with name Y) and pass that URL to the user for them to use. Signed URLs are only valid for as long as you like (one of the parameters is how long the URL is good for).

Documentation on signed URLs are here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs